# How do I set up GWT global modules in JBoss AS 7?

Tags: gwt, jboss, module, ejb-3.0

Folks,

I’m using JBoss AS 7 to publish my projects and all of them use the ejb and gwt, so instead of deploying it in every project I wanted to create a module for it. I created the folder JBOSS_HOME\modules\com\google\gwt\main and then I do not know what I need to do.  I've seen on this [guide](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/running-drools-5-4-0-final-as-a-jboss-as-7-module.html) there was contained `module.xml`. How do I set up GWT global modules in JBoss?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to read up on JBoss Modules [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Home), the link in your question isn't he bet resource imo.

Comment: I created file module.xml in JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/google/gwt/main and I put jar file into that folder. I tried access them in jboss-deployment-structure.xml following :

<module name="com.google.gwt" slot="main" >
            <imports>
                <include path="META-INF/**"/>
                <include path="**"/>
            </imports>
        </module>

but i'm getting error : Error loading module from/home/sholihin/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/com/google/gwt/main/module.xml
can you help me to solve the problem?